# ReactJs StyledComponent and ClassName

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Hello I have a problem I believe my code is getting too big for simple things

Basically I have a wrap for the site:

```
export const Wrapper = styled.div`
    min-height:100vh !important;
`;
```

and my header is this now:

```
    <Styled.WrapHeader>
        <DefaultContainer>
            <Styled.NavStickey />
        </DefaultContainer>
    </Styled.WrapHeader>
```

I used 3 divs to make something simple a div with 100% width and a container where the navbar will be
css:

```
const WrapHeader = styled.div`
    background: #1269DB;
    height: 130px;
    width:100%;
`;

const NavStickey = styled.div`
    width:100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: red;   
`;
```

And here I have my container:

```
export const DefaultContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: transparent !important;
`
```

What I think is very big I wanted to separate the margins and padding of the container for a class and call className in the div how would I get this in the styled?

like this:

```
.divct{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        justify-content: space-between;
        background: transparent !important;
}
.container {
        max-width: 1000px;
        padding: 0px 30px;
        margin: 0px auto;
}

div className = "divct container"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create snippets of css templates like this:

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'

// Not a styled component, just a css template.
const DivContainer = css`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: transparent !important;
`

const Container = css`
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  margin: 0px auto;
`
```

You can then compose them into a styled component, kind of how you would join two classNames in a regular component:

```
const WrapHeader = styled.div`
  background: #1269DB;
  height: 130px;
  width:100%;
  ${DivContainer}
  ${Container}
`
```

This works just like any other template string (because that's what they are). So the result will have all the styles merged, like this:

```
// This is what the result will look like internally.
const WrapHeader = styled.div`
  background: #1269DB;
  height: 130px;
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: transparent !important;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  margin: 0px auto;
`
```